# HIVE Select columns names with regular expression?

Tags: hive

I want to know if it can be queried about the columns in the hive ith term rehiliare selection for the starting columns of some description?

example:
table with this list of names of columns
pattern1 pattern2 motif3 balab1 balabal2 ma1 ma2 ma3

select (an expression for that selection columns beginners with pattern)
from table

Thank you

Comment: Hi malouke, to get answers in SO you need to frame questions that should explain exact problem and some code snippets (if any) which u are having issues.

Answer (score 10):

I believe you are looking to select columns based on regular expression.

Well below works:

```
  set hive.support.quoted.identifiers=none;
  select `patt.*` from test_table;
```

Above code will return columns pattern1 pattern2 among your mentioned columns  "pattern1 pattern2 motif3 balab1 balabal2 ma1 ma2 ma3"

Please see https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Select#LanguageManualSelect-REGEXColumnSpecification for more information.

Comment: I have also tried this it does not work :SELECT `(ds|hr)?+.+` FROM sales

Comment: Which version of hive are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use back quote character (above tilda in the keyboard not the single quote) after select and before from to run regular expression in the hive.