# Hive: joining multiple tables with same key

Tags: sql, hive

I am trying to join multiple tables in hive which have a common key `col`

```
create table merged_table as
select a.*,b.*,c.* from table1 a
join table 2 b
on a.col = b.col
join table3 c
on c.col = d.col
```

But this gives the following error:

> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10036]: Duplicate column name: col

These tables have many columns. Is there any way by which this can be done without explicitly writng the column names in the query?

Comment: You need to rename `col` column in select as `select a.*,b.*,c.*` will produce three columns with name `col`, that's why you receive `Duplicate column name: col` error. For instance `select a.col as col_a, b.col as col_b` etc.

Comment: This appears to be a SQL question, not an HQL question. Note the [tag:hql] stands for Hibernate Query Language, not Hive Query Language

Comment: @serge_k so will this work `select a.col as col_a, b.col as col_b, c.col as col_c, a.*, b.*, c.*`? or you mean to say that I have to explicitly specify what all columns are needed?

Comment: @LukasEder okay

Comment: @prashanth your select won't work neither, you need to specify all the columns explicitly . Or you can select your columns using regex, i.e. select all but `col` plus `col` from either table, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33633071/hive-select-columns-names-with-regular-expression

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a table with duplicate column names. While it is possible in SQL top level `SELECT` statements to produce ambiguous / duplicate column names, such queries cannot be used in `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT`. You should rename each individual column name, possibly prefixing them all with the origin table name:

```
create table merged_table as
select a.col1 as a_col1, a.col2 as a_col2, ..., b.col1 as b_col1, ...
from table1 a
join table2 b on a.col = b.col
join table3 c on b.col = c.col
```