# how to select the columns with specified words in their names and their values are equal to specified values in hive sql on databricks

Tags: python, sql, hive, hiveql, databricks

I am trying to select some columns that have names with some specific words in hive sql on databricks.

Based on [HIVE Select columns names with regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33633071/hive-select-columns-names-with-regular-expression)

my code:

```
  %py
  t = spark.createDataFrame([('50', 'rscds', 'tyhdvs'),], ['id', 'col_pattern_1', 'col_pattern_2'])
  t.write.saveAsTable('my_database.my_table')

  %sql 
  set hive.support.quoted.identifiers=none;
  select `col_pattern.*` 
  from my_database.my_table
```

I got:

```
 Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`col_pattern.*`' given input
```

I tried:

```
 import pyspark.sql.functions as F
 selected = [s for s in t.columns if 'col_pattern' in s]
 t.filter(t[x]=='rscds' for x in selected)
```

i got:

```
  TypeError: condition should be string or Column
```

input:

```
  the dataframe may have 20+ columns with the same prefix, I cannot type them in the query one by one, so I need to find a way to filter the DF by all the columns with the same prefix by a given value.    

 +---+-------------+-------------+-------------+
 | id|col_pattern_1|col_pattern_2|col_pattern_3|
 +---+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 50|        rscds|       tyhdvs|        tyhdvs|
 +---+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

output:

```
 e.g. I need to find the rows with the column that has the given prefix ('col_pattern') and its value == 'rscds'

  +---+-------------+
  | id|col_pattern_1|
  +---+-------------|
  | 50|        rscds|
  +---+-------------+
```

select the columns that have names with specified words and also it values == a specified value.

thanks

Comment: what is the input and what is the expected output?

Comment: please see the updated OP. thanks